# Change a div`s background image when hover over the image

Tags: html, css, image, background

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html >
 <head> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
        .imgBox {background: url(lock75.png) no-repeat; } 
        .imgBox:hover {background: url(lock75light.png) no-repeat; } 
    </style> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div style="width:200px; height:200px; border:1px solid;" class="imgBox"> </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

My images are 75x75 and the problem occurs that when I hover over the border the image changes, I want when hovering over the image to change the image.

Note: I need a html construction similar to this one.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that I need the picture to be centralized above the other divs which I have not a certain space for the picture.

Thanks

Comment: reduced `div` width to 75px.

Comment: Similar to which one?

Comment: Not possible I have other content in the div except the image.

Comment: You have to create an extra div for images.

Comment: @AdamAzad A little more about your idea please? I have content (others divs buttons etc). Do you mean to place to other div above my divs with z-index or something?

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle I created http://jsfiddle.net/aoe1e8r0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a container that can hold both the background image and your content in the following structure (I know you asked for something similar to what you have posted, but it's not possible; well it is but it will involve CSS3 elements and jQuery)

Here's the setup

```css
body {
    padding:10px;
}
.img-box {
    max-width:200px;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}
.img-box .img {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background: url(https://unsplash.it/200/200/?image=876) no-repeat;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}
.img-box .img:hover {
    background: url(https://unsplash.it/200/200/?image=876&blur) no-repeat;
}
p { margin:5px }
```

```html
<div class="img-box">
    <div class="img" ></div>
    <p>other content here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need the picture to be centralized above the other divs which I have not a certain space for the picture.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for this:

```css
.container {
    border:1px solid #000;
    display:inline-block;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
}
.imgBox {
    background:url(http://placehold.it/100x100) no-repeat;
    height:75px;
    width:75px;
} 
.imgBox:hover {
    background:url(http://placehold.it/75x75) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="imgBox"> </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I need the picture to be centralized above the other divs which I have not a certain space for the picture.